# GCC compiler does not search sub-directories when looking for header files

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, include-path

I can't make gcc compiler recognize complex paths in "includes".

Here's my toy "main.cpp" file (note the sub-directory in the include statement):

```
#include "sub/testlib.h"

int main()
{
    testlib(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the path to the file "testlib.h" from the folder "main.cpp" lives in: ../lib/sub/testlib.h.

I'm specifying the include directory while compiling:

```
gcc -c -iquote../lib main.cpp
```

And the compiler yells at me:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: sub/testlib.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "sub/testlib.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Of course I can make it compile by removing sub-directory from the path. But this is just an experiment I make after having failed to compile a real-world project. I can't freely change the files there.

How do I force gcc to treat sub-directories well in the includes? Is there a flag or some option that I'm missing here?

Comment: You can try adding `-I/sub`

Comment: Please [edit] and show the absolute path of each of the files. What is `-iquote../lib`

Comment: @NutCracker, I did but the problem is still there...

Comment: @Jabberwocky, silly me. As you suggested, I started editing and found out the paths were not what I supposed them to be. I changed the paths and it worked like a charm then! Thank you for saving me hours of wrong guesses and tries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I force gcc to treat sub-directories well in the includes? Is there a flag or some option that I'm missing here?

Read the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), in particular the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter, the section on [*preprocessor options*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) (e.g. `-I` *include-dir* or `-H` or `-M`, etc...), the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) of the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Try also `g++ --help` ; the  `-I` *include-directory*  flag can be repeated a lot of times and is probably what you need. Of course, order of arguments to the `g++` program matters a lot. You probably want to use `g++` not `gcc` when compiling or linking C++ programs.

Read also [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) of C++ (maybe even the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) "draft" standard). Be aware of [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), and of the role of the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

In practice, you want to drive GCC compilation using some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or many others.

If you use GNU `make`, read its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) then try `make -p` which shows the many built-in rules known to that software. Be aware of the [many functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html) of `make`.

If you use `ninja`, read its [documentation](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html), you probably want to *generate* the `build.ninja`  script it is using. You could generate it using a [Python](https://python.org) script or a [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) one (or your own C++ program, etc...).

Be aware that of course `g++`   will invoke some GNU [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) utilities (e.g. the assembler `as`  or the linker `ld`).

Practically speaking, invoke `g++` as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  to get warnings and debug information (of course with additional `-I` *include-directory* flags). Then use the [`gdb` debugger](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Once your program has few bugs, add optimization flags such as  `-O2`

See also [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), its [static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), and [CompCert](https://compcert.org/) and, at end of 2020, [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/).

Consider in some cases to generate some `#include`-d C++ code (e.g. with [SWIG](http://swig.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) or your own script) or to extend GCC with your [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

Be of course aware of the [Joel Test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/).

Comment: Thank you! I certainly will spend more time reading the docs. I'm still too inexperienced, making typos and believing it has something to do with the compiler itself.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, trust the compiler much more than yourself. The GCC project has very strong code review practices.

Comment: That's a lot of links. But your answer doesn't really make much sense to me as your answer isn't self contained. It looks like you've basically just said GTFO&RTFM.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes indeed. I am a big advocate of reading documentation; I strongly believe people should spend more time in reading it. Writing any kind of documentation is a lot of efforts.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I read and have written enough documentation to understand that. However the presence of documentation doesn't justify writing incoherent nonsense.